# Mysql subquery slow

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that track sales:

```
orders                 order_line_items
------                 ----------------
id                     id
customer_id            order_id
created_datetime       item_id
                       quantity
                       was_paid_for
```

An `order` can have many `order_line_items`.  For some orders, all of the line items have been paid for.  For other orders, they have not all been paid for.

I am trying to fetch a list of all the orders for a specific customer, and indicate if the order was fully paid for, or not.  I have it working with this query:

```
SELECT o.id,
       (SELECT count(*) from order_line_items WHERE order_id = o.id AND was_paid_for = 0) = 0 as isFullyPaid
FROM orders o
WHERE o.customer_id = 12345
```

However some customers have 1000+ orders and the query takes 70 seconds to run (this is a simplified example, the real one joins in five other tables).

Is indexes the only way to speed this up?  Thanks.

Comment: You have an index on order_id?

Comment: No I don't; I haven't set up any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding the following index to the `order_line_items`:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON order_line_items(order_id, was_paid_for);
```

That being said, you also could try using the following join version of your query:

```sql
SELECT o.id, COALESCE(oli.cnt, 0) = 0 AS isFullyPaid
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT order_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM order_line_items
    WHERE was_paid_for = 0
    GROUP BY order_id
) oli
    ON oli.order_id = o.id
WHERE o.customer_id = 12345;
```

The same index suggestion applied to the above join query.

Comment: Thanks very much. Interesting, adding the index improved the original query speed from 70 seconds down to 2 seconds.  Running your new query with NO indexes also brought the time down to 2 seconds.  Running your new query WITH indexes didn't have any further improvements.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  How can your suggestion deliver the same results when you are NOT selecting WHERE o.customer_id = 12345 ?

Comment: @WilsonHauck It can't, and you're correct.  I fixed it, thanks.